# How can I login to the same website, different accounts, different proxies, at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, watin

Hei guys, I want to make a testing program to login to the same website, with different accounts and different proxies, so that all the accounts will be online at the same time from different proxies. No need for other stuff, just to login.

I tried to use Watin, even though, I can set IE to nomerge, I still can't use different proxies for every session.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible from watin, you can do it directly from the WebRequest but not by using watin.